# LG Android Phone keeps making Windows say Unknown Device

Tags: android, windows-7, driver, adb

I am trying to use my LG Revolution to develop an Android app but Windows 7 (64-bit) keeps telling me that it's an Unknown device

I've tried downloading drivers from LG's site as well as the ones that Verizon shipped but I can't get ADB/Fastboot to recognize that the phone is attached.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to stop all the related programs to the LG, in the task manager, because sometimes ADB can't reach the phone because of the running programs, which are related to the Phone. If it's not working try to uninstall all of the programs what related to the phone ( including the drivers, and then try to reinstall the drivers first, and the drivers, what Windows suggest.

Hope it helps.